# coldfusion hang after file upload

Tags: coldfusion, timeout, freeze

I have a page that accepts user images, renames them and returns the new filename for further processing

```
<cffunction name="uploadfile" access="public" returntype="string">
<!--- TODO files should not be uploaded to web accesible directories - use #GetTempDirectory()# to use the temporary directory--->
        <cfargument name="forma" type="struct" required="yes">
        <cfargument name="db" type="string" required="yes">
        <cfargument name="user_id" type="string" required="yes">              
        <cfparam name="new_filename" default="">  
        <cfset mediapath = expandpath('/ugc_images/images')>
        <cfset thumbpath = expandpath('/ugc_images/images/thumbs')>

        <cfif structKeyExists(forma,"fileUpload") and len(forma.fileUpload)>
             <cffile action="upload"  filefield="FileUpload" destination="#MediaPath#" nameconflict="makeunique" accept="image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png">
             <!---<cfset serverfile.extension = right(file.serverFile, 3)>             --->
             <cfset new_filename= "#user_id#_#DateFormat(Now(), "mm-dd-yyyy")#.jpg">          
             <cffile action="rename" source="#MediaPath#/#file.serverFile#" destination="#MediaPath#/#new_filename#"/>
         <cfimage source="#MediaPath#/#new_filename#" name="myImage">   
         <cfset ImageSetAntialiasing(myImage,"on")>          
         <cfif myImage.width gt 1000 or myImage.height gt 1000><cfset ImageScaleToFit(myImage,1000,1000)> </cfif>                   
         <cfset ImageWrite(myImage,"#MediaPath#/#new_filename#")>   
         <cfif myImage.width gt 300 or myImage.height gt 300><cfset ImageScaleToFit(myImage,300,300)></cfif>        
         <cfset ImageWrite(myImage,"#thumbpath#/#new_filename#")>


        </cfif>

    <cfreturn "#new_filename#"> 
    </cffunction><!---EO uploadfile--->
```

after calling that function (which does indeed upload and save the file and its thumbnail as intended, all coldfusion fucntions seem to hang. The webserver still serves plain text, but any coldfusion tag no matter how simple, timesout
for example, after the above I have this:

```
    This text is served to the browser
<hr>
        and this
<hr>
        <cfoutput >but this times out</cfoutput>
        and it never gets here
        <hr>
```

It all works well on my local machine for development but on the remote (production) server it crashes. It's on a shared hosting so I have limited access to settings

any idea what's going on?

Comment: Have you tried doing things bit by bit - strip out all the resizing and see if it hangs with just the upload?

Comment: It doesn't help your issue, but your UDF has some problems. Not only do you not var scope anything, which is a huge issue, you also misuse pounds/quotes. For ex, cfreturn "#new_filename#" can be/should be cfreturn new_filename.

Comment: The problem fixed itself! ... and then it failed.
I could upload once then on the second (identical) test it crashed. It was the same before. I managed to get it to work once, then on the second attempt it timed out on the cfoutput - or whatever CF tag it encounters inmediarly after returning from the function
P.S.  Thanks for the var scoping tip- I clearly a noob  - I'll look up what is best practice on this.

Comment: What version of CF is this? Take a look in the /runtime/logs (where they are depends on version and installation type). or /runtime/bin. I suspect you have a hotspot error associated with your IMAGE operation. I bet if you commented out the image maniputlations it would no longer hang. A hotspot error might give you a clue. If not try the standard out logs. (they look like "cfusion-out.log" and they are found under /runtime/logs in a basic standard install).

Comment: I don't have access to the logs on the shared host - but in the end I moved the whole thing to another server and it seems to work. (the new host is on railo if that makes any difference)

Comment: @MarkAKruger I think you where right, the image processing tags where causing hangups (didn't know re-sizing was so processor intensive)
I found a tip on an optional setting for the tag - "highestperformance" and it is much faster  - I also remove dthe second image generation tag that created thumbnails http://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2012/5/28/cf_image_resizing_problem_and_solution